# Private npm/git dependencies on Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, git, google-app-engine, npm

I'm using Google App Engine's new custom runtimes to develop some applications, and the need has risen to extract code to be pulled in as dependencies. These dependencies are either added from a private npm repository, or private git repositories.

How can I set up my GAE project to use such private repositories, without checking in sensitive details into the repository itself? (Git and/or npm doesn't matter; would prefer git.)

Answer (score 0):

**The traditional way to do this is to have a file with the creds on the server**. When your app needs the creds, it reads the file and sends them through the (assuming) secure channel to whoever needs to inspect them. If you were running on pure compute engine, having a persistent disk isn't a problem, but then you have to manage and spin up instances to load balance yourself.

**Thinking about the traditional persistent disk hardware-linked to the runtime as merely a specific class of persistent data-store**, you might see where I'm going: access to your GCS Bucket/Datastore/Cloud SQL (all of them a kind of persistent data-store) is secured by the use of OAuth with your project's service account or the datacenter-level security of a Cloud SQL unix socket in the last case, ensuring the creds aren't accessible to anybody but you while being stored.

Compare: the disk files containing the creds were protected in the traditional example by the fact that no other computer could access the disk without the explicit permission of the operating system, which would have to be deliberately configured to accept such a connection (and then you would be implementing some kind of authorization/authentication scheme to ensure the security of this connection).

OAuth2.0 is widely used in the google cloud platform, which ensures the same connections to the instance's persistent store (whichever you choose) can take place while also being already supplied with a strong authorization/authentication scheme. In the case of Cloud SQL, the auth system can be as simple as your username and pass with a secure tunnel. The question merely becomes one of transferring the creds from your machine to where they can be accessed by the runtime.

So, you can:

- [Use the the gsutil tool](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil) to put an object containing the creds and set this object's ACL so that it belongs exclusively to your app's service account
- [Use the remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/articles/remote_api) to put a Datastore entity containing the creds
- [Connect to your Cloud SQL instance through a locally-running client](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/external) and insert the data. (Note for this option that you're not using OAuth from your local client, but [hopefully a secure tunnel](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/instances#ssl) and the authentication factor of a db username and password. When the managed VM wants to access the instance, it takes place within google's network, so you can be assured of the security of that connection).

...and at this point [you can access the creds, wherever they're stored, from your managed VM](http://i.giphy.com/RYP0QcyO2ZGN2.gif).

Comment: It's worth noting at this point that if those services used OAuth to have you grant your app scoped access to that data, the process would be a lot simpler and the concept of storing your creds would be avoided at all. That's the whole point of OAuth: to prevent cred duplication in storage, keeping it in people's minds and 2-factor auth devices, <s>sticky notes beside their computer</s>, etc. I guess one could see services that use OAuth sign-in pages provided by external organizations but don't implement OAuth to make their data scope-accessible as kind of lame net citizens...

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot for all that - much obliged! Not sure I'm much smarter though, forgive my ignorance. My problem isn't so much with finding credentials at *run time*, but at *build time*. The way things are set up with managed VMs on App Engine - unless I'm mistaken - is that dependencies are installed when the docker instance is built, and so that's where the credentials need to come into play. I don't want to check in these with the project, since it's sensitive, and I'm not sure how to set this up otherwise. Maybe you've answered this, but I've got to admit I got a bit lost - my apologies!

Comment: Can you post the relevant portions of the docker file, shell script etc. that actually runs the install for these packages? It seems like you'll either have some way of grabbing the creds from one of those storage options, or you'll need to bundle the creds with your source when deploying but `gitignore` them so you don't have to worry about your repository. A third option is to bundle the actual libs with your source when deploying - using a build tool like maven, grunt, gradle, etc. to download and include the private libs just before your deploy action.